# More companions in Fallout: New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Is there any way in which you can have more than one follower? In Fallout 3, I had four.

Answer (score 8):

Without the use of mods, in New Vegas you can have one Humanoid (Human/ghoul/super mutant) companion, and one of either Rex or Ed-E (robot companions).

There are several mods that increase the companion limit.

In addition, you can gain temporary companions through the use of items like the NCR emergency radio.

Comment: Is Dogmeat (or any other dog) in FNV?

Comment: @Asad Dogmeat is not. There is however, a dog companion in the form of Rex, the Kings cyborg dog. You can find him in Freeside.

Comment: which mods let one get more followers?